# insert foreach controllers on CodeIgniter

Tags: php, codeigniter, foreach

I want to try to add foreach on controllers , because before I show you foreach on views

This my Controllers

```
$data['report_data'] = $this->hasil_m->get_data($nomor);

//create foreach here, from data $data['report_data']


$data=array('title'     =>'KOPKAR - Pelanggan',
            'isi'       =>'admin/hasil'
);          
$this->load->view('dashboard/wrapper',$data);
```

This my Models

```
$this->db->select('*');
$this->db->from('tb_produk as pro');
$this->db->join('tb_reseller as res', 'pro.reseller_produk  = res.nomor_reseller');
$this->db->join('tb_pelanggan as pel', 'pro.id_barcode  = pel.id_barcode'); 
$this->db->select_sum('jumlah');
$this->db->group_by('res.nomor_reseller');
$ambil = $this->db->get('');
if ($ambil->num_rows() > 0) {
    foreach ($ambil->result() as $data) {
        $hasil[] = $data;
    }
    return $hasil;
}
```

This my Views

Comment: what do you want ?

Comment: i want create foreach on controllers from `$data['report_data'] = $this->hasil_m->get_data($nomor);` , usually i create foreach on views

Comment: yeah its ok, but what do you want to do in this controller. there must be a reason in order to do that

Comment: I wanted to call up data from the join table , there is a separate data so if you want to call the data I mush to create two foreach

Comment: ok so you have 2 models -> one model returns report data and another model has additional data for your reports is that correct ?

if so please post your 2 models here and your controller

Comment: I only use the first models to display all the data I need, i try upload my views but error on script

Answer (score 0):

Instead of doing :

```
foreach ($ambil->result() as $data) {
    $hasil[] = $data;
}
return $hasil;
```

just

```
return $ambil->result_array();
```

Comment: i'm not sure what you want to answer here... result returns an array with each row as an object and result_array an array with each row as an array

Comment: You return it as this and then you don't have to do foreach in model, and after that when you pass `$data['report_data']` to view, just do `foreach($report_data as $r)`

Comment: you are right you dont need a foreach here, but the problem is $ambil->result() returns as i said an array where each row is an object and your method returns an array where each row itself is an array - thats a total different thing and ops method returns an array where each row is an object - so i dont think your answer helps here

Comment: Ok, you need to describe your problem better then, because I don't understand what you need, I thought you have problem with foreach